# Best way to implement a watermark on all the product's photos?

Tags: watermark

Magento 1.9.1

If I remember correctly - there should be a utility within Magento to add the same watermark to all the product's photos automatically? Does this work well or do you recommend a different approach to adding watermarks?

An important question - if I add watermarks to all the product images using the utility within Magento - would it be possible (easy) to remove the water mark in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its depend on your requirement that you want to use watermark or not.

But if you want to use watermark You can use this way

Go to `System->Configuration->Design`

and click on `Product Image Watermarks`

tab and fill out the details

and if you want to discontinue with this feature then

go to phpmyadmin and  fire this query `SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%watermark%'`

and delete all data

after that go to `system->cache Managment` and press `flush catalog image cache` button

and refresh magento cache

Comment: Thank you Murtuza - just to make sure I understand - Implementing the Watermarks will put them on the photos and then, when I run the query in phpmyadmin - it will delete the watermarks from the existing photos so they will no longer have it on there? Thanks!

Comment: yes You are right after this query flush catalog image cache so new product image will be generated at frontend

Comment: Murtuza Zabuawala: If I were to download all photos to my computer before doing this - are they all stored in a folder somewhere? Thanks! ;-)

Comment: @Allysin all photos were stored in `media/catalog/product`  folder but you dont need to download all photos as magento generate all frontend photos run time and stored them in cache